# What checks has Mono performed when System.Net.ServerCertificateValidationCallback is triggered?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to secure my connection to a server in a Mono (actually MonoTouch) application. Therefore I have hooked up to `System.Net.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)`

Is this callback supposed to trigger with an error in case of a man-in-the-middle attack? Or will this case not be detected if the fake certificate's name matches the real one?

Is the check identical to how Microsoft implements it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback allow you to customize the behaviour of your application wrt SSL/TLS results. Common customization are discussed in this article: [Using Trusted Roots Respectfully](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully)

The basic validation are done by [System.Net.ServicePointManager](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/ServicePointManager.cs#L455) (link to Mono sources). They differ a bit per platform. For MonoTouch it's basically a call to iOS to see if the certificate(s) are valid. Additional, **HTTPS** specific, checks are done on top of that (to match the RFC requirements for HTTP over SSL/TLS).

> Is this callback supposed to trigger with an error in case of a man-in-the-middle attack?

Any error will be reported. That includes invalid signatures of certificates that could ne used for a MitM attack. OTOH most errors are more benign (e.g. expiration dates).

> Or will this case not be detected if the fake certificate's name matches the real one?

HTTPS RFC requires the certificate name (generally the CN) to match the name of the web site - IOW it will be detected (as long as you can trust your DNS - but that's true for every implementation ;-).

> Is the check identical to how Microsoft implements it?

Microsoft does not really document this in much details. However it will follow the X.509 checks and the HTTPS RFC so it should be pretty close.

Comment: From what I see, the "chain" property is always NULL in MonoTouch. This prevents me to check if the certificates is derived from a trusted root CA. I have the situation here that a certificate has the correct name of the website but still is issued by an attacker. Of source this cert does not come from Geotrust or others - so how to verify in MT?

Comment: By default this check has been has already been done, by iOS, for you. You can dig the source from `_TrustEvaluateSsl` downward to see how it was done (open source). If you're using an **untrusted** root then iOS won't accept it (and any chain would be incomplete as HTTPS servers do not have to send their chain, just their own certificate). Validating a chain is extremely complex (and time consuming). You can do it, using Mono's `X509Chain`, by looking how this is done for other platforms (all but `MONOTOUCH` and `MONODROID` defines).

Comment: I'll see if I can submit a test case but from what I have tried so far: my Safari (Mac OS) is complaining about a certificate that has been issued by our company's CA. It says,the root is untrusted. On the iPhone however, the callback does not indicate any problems. No error, chain is NULL. According to your comment I should get an error, right?

Comment: I don't see why MT would not check the chain if iOS doesn't do it either. That's a bug to me. The behavior should be the same in MONO and MonoTouch. Can't be that the certificate is OKAY in MT and not in MONO - or do I misunderstand something here; at least iOS doesn't seem to check the chain, hence: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5546

Comment: iOS should be doing the check (or it's a bug) but the final result might vary between MonoTouch and Mono as the (trusted) roots and installed (intermediate) CA certificates are likely different (just like Mono and Windows don't always get the same result, updating Mono using `mozroots` generally fixes such issues).

Comment: Well, then just check out the bug and contact me if there's something unclear. Currently, MT is validating the cert "OK" even though the root cert from the CA is not available, while Mono and Windows throw an error.

Comment: Bug fixed, it will be part of 5.2.13 (next stable) and 5.3.5 (next unstable). An hotfix is available on the bug report (to use on top of 5.2.12). The validated chain is not available but you'll have an error condition on an invalid certificate (and you'll have to choose what to do with it based on the server certificate).

Answer (score 0):

According to msdn, [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx), it is used for any custom validation performed by the client. For example, if you want to override a self-signed certificate's validation in a development environment.

Comment: Yeah, but it obviously already does some checks before because it is passing me an SslPolicyErrors enum. I'm especially interested if it is performing checks on the chain.

Comment: Feasibly, it passes you an SslPolicyErrors enum so you can set the value yourself and pass it up the logic chain to whatever interface is presented to user or automated process.

Comment: Still, that does not explain why it contains an error if the name of the certificate does not match the name of the server; however if the name's match, there is no error. The base is obviously doing something and sets the enum's value accordingly. It seems to find "basic" issues - but which ones?

Comment: This is a guess, but: Server name and certificate name, expiration and issuing authority for every certificate in the chain.